# Are static variables internal or external in C++

Tags: c++, static-variables

Are static variables in C++ internal variables or external variables? Or can be both?

---

PS: It seems to me that (not sure it's correct):

- Internal variables are assigned their values at compile time.
- External variables are assigned their values at link time.

Comment: One question per question, please. And both have likely been asked before, so do some searching!

Comment: _'internal variables or external'_ It's a bit unclear for me what you mean with this. Internal/external in relation to what? Compilation units, classes, ...??

Comment: @herohuyongtao So you mean internal/external in relation to compilation units? The c++ `static` keyword has nothing to do with this, it just controls if a member appears per class or instance of a class.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `static` can change the linkage, for example used on variables of namespace scope. I.e. `static` has multiple meanings. (There are also block-scope static variables inside functions.)

Comment: @dyp Yes, you're right, I forgot about this aspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialization depends on the type of the static variable.

1. With fundamental types and initial values that can be computed at compile time, the variables initial value should be layed down in a section of the executable that is mapped into memory with copy on write semantics.
2. However, the compiler can also decide to initialize `static` variables at runtime, typically before `main()` gets executed. But afaik, the only constraint is that initialization is finished when the variable is first used, and that static variables within a compilation unit are initialized in the order they are written (in case their initializers depend on one another).

The point is, that `static` variables are initialized before they are used by code called from `main()`, but it is not specified when this initialization happens. The compiler can do what it deems most efficient.

In any case, static variables live at least until `main()` exits or `exit()` is called. I am pretty sure that C++ will also call the destructors before terminating the process, but I don't know about that.

Answer (score 2):

According to the C++ Standard

> 3 A name having namespace scope (3.3.6) has internal linkage if it is
>   the name of — a variable, function or function template that is
>   **explicitly declared static**; or,

As for your statement that

> PS: I learned that  • Internal variables are assigned their values at
>   compile time.
>
> • External variables are assigned their values at link time.

then it is wrong.

In my opinion you are trying to mix up two notions: static storage duration and program linkage.